# how to make resque process jobs ordered

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I have a queue which process some 'Products' thar are sent via JSON. I receive them in a order like {1, 2, 3, 4}, but resque processed them in {1, 3, 2, 4}. It is pretty important that resque process they ordered because a old version of `Product` can override a new version thar was already processed
Is there a way to tell resque like `process {job} orderede by {job.field_I_want}`?

edit: the code that enqueue the job

```
def produto
        if params[:json]
#          upload = params[:json]
#          content = upload.read
#          parsed_json = JSON(content)

          parsed_json = JSON(params[:json])
          parsed_json['idFila'] = params[:idFila]

          logger.info parsed_json

          Resque.enqueue(ProdutoWorker, parsed_json)
          render json: ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(Retorno.new(:status => "OK", :mensagem => "Produto recebido")), :status => :ok
        else
          render json: ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(Retorno.new(:status => "Erro", :mensagem => "Sem JSON")), :status => :not_found
        end

        rescue => exception
          render json: ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(Retorno.new(:status => "Erro", :mensagem => "#{exception}")), :status => :error
      end #Produto
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resque processes the jobs in the order they are queued, can you post the code that enqueue the jobs?

Comment: I can't say much with that code, I guess the problem is that hashes doesn't have an order, try doing something like this on your worker's perform method:
parsed_json.keys.sort.each do |key|
  process(parsed_json[key])
end

what's the relevant code of the perform method of your resque worker?

Comment: Hashes in Ruby 1.9 preserve order.